# Google Auth for Ionic App

Tags: ionic-framework, oauth, google-plus

i'm using `cordova-plugin-googleplus` for authentication with google accounts in my Ionic app.

I've done all the steps listed in [docs](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus), but it stills doesn't working. I've got the diabolic **12501 error**.

I have the credentials and i'm calling the authentication method using:

```
    vm.loginWithGoogle = () => {
        console.log('Login with google', window.plugins.googleplus);
        window.plugins.googleplus.login(
            {webClientId:'my-credentials'},
            success => console.log('success', success),
            error => console.log('error', error)
        );
    }
```

Somebody passed through this before?

Answer (score 1):

just now i'm facing this issue. solved by

1. on "ionic plugin add", reverse your key you got from google console
2. sign your app with key generated from keytool that you used for google console

regards,